# Передать переменную в другой файл php через клик

Tags: php, html

Есть такой скрипт

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($deviceCount as $value) {
    echo str_starts_with($value, 'SEP') ? "$i. " . "<a href = http://tools.ru/otherscript.php>$value</a><br>\n" : "$i. $value<br>\n";        
    $i++;
}
```

ссылка выводится на страницу, при нажатии на нее выполняется другой скрипт php на другой странице, в который как то должно передаваться $value. Через кнопку мне понятно как делать (POST), но как обработать нажатие по ссылке ((

Comment: делать через GET :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передать значение можно через [URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) запроса, такие значения будут доступны в глобальном массиве `$_GET` и `$_REQUEST`. Получить его можно будет например так: `$_GET["value"]`, хотя лучше использовать специальный метод `filter_input(INPUT_GET,"value")`;

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($deviceCount as $value) {
    $url = "http://tools.ru/otherscript.php?".http_build_query([
            "value" => $value
        ]);
    echo str_starts_with($value, 'SEP')
        ? "$i. <a href=\"{$url}\">$value</a><br>\n"
        : "$i. $value<br>\n";        
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Одно уточнение, если у вас запрос будет по методу POST то переменные в массиве REQUEST НЕ будут дублировать массив GET... (комбинированный метод передачи, когда используются и POST и GET параметры, но тип запроса установлен как POST)